# How to print two fields in separate rows from a query result?

Tags: python

So I have this code here:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT question, answer FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")

myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

for row in myresult:
    print(row)
```

But this prints the random question along with its corresponding answer as one string. How can I print the question and answer as two different strings but keep them from the same random row?

Comment: display only  `row[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an index to select specific rows:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT question, answer FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")

myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

print("\nPrinting each row")
for row in myresult:
    print(“question = ", row[0])
    print("answer = ", row[1])
```

Read more about it [here](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/).